# I got this hydration error in the initial stage of my project

Tags: reactjs, next.js, runtime-error, next.js13, hydration

When I use nextjs for my project at the initial stage it give me a error
This is the error
Error: Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server.

Warning: Expected server HTML to contain a matching  in .

and this is my code

layout.js

```
import '../styles/globals.css';

export const metadata = {
    title: "Twitter",
    description: 'Share tweets'
}

const RootLayout = ({children}) => {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <title>{metadata.title}</title>
        <meta name="description" content={metadata.description} />
      </head>
      <body>
        <div className="text-3xl">
          {children}
        </div>
      </body>
    </html>
  )
}

export default RootLayout
```

and page.js

```
import React from "react"

const page = () => {
  return (
    <h1> 
        PAge
    </h1>
  )
}

export default page
```

Help me to fix this error